# Covering the case when no function is passed to another function

Tags: javascript

I have a function that can be passed a complete function.
I don't want to invoke complete if it is not null so I do

```
function queryJS(sql, success, error, complete) { 
...
...
if (complete !== null) complete()
...
...
```

When I invoke the function with 3 params such as:

```
queryJS("SELECT BLAH FROM TABLE", mysuccess, myerror)
```

I get:

```
TypeError: complete is not a function
```

What are my doing wrong?

And what is the best way to cover the case of no complete function passed.

Thanks

Comment: You're using complete as a function in `if (complete !== null) complete()` while it's not

Comment: Maybe it is not null but it is undefined instead? e.g. `typeof complete === "undefined"`

Comment: If you did the comparison with `!=` then it would work, though the suggestions that you actually check to see if it's present *and* a function are good ones.

Answer (score 5):

An empty argument is always `undefined`.
So you should check if `complete` is a function:

```
if (typeof complete === "function") {
  complete();
}
```

To throw an error for invalid `complete` values you could check either for `undefined` or
for the arguments array length:

```
if (typeof complete !== "undefined") {
  complete();
}

if (arguments.length >= 4) {
  complete();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Because it would be undefined, not null

```
if (complete !== undefined) complete()
```

A simple debug statement above the statement would have shown you that.

```
console.log(complete);
```

Comment: I'd use this one. Answers with `typeof == function` are less correct. If a parameter is passed, it must be called in any case (and throw an exception on the wrong type). Otherwise a potential bug would be silently ignored - this is _very_ bad.

Comment: If this function was created by another developer and I don't want a callback to be executed, I have 2 options: I can pass only 3 attributes or pass null. if I pass null the function fails and I would wonder why because I don't want complete to be used at all. Comparisons in JavaScript should be against type (typeof,isArray, isinstanceof,hasOwnProperty) comparisons against null or undefined are a bad practice.

Comment: @OweRReLoaDeD Checking against null and undefined is not a bad practice. That is your personal opinion. The whole idea if the error should be thrown or not is chosen by the developer. I rather see an error. And if your reasoning of `undefined` can be overwritten with a different value, modern day browsers now prevent it.

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to deal with this is to check if `complete` is a function or not.

```
if (typeof complete == 'function') {
    complete();
}
```

You also create a function to try the argument e.g.

```
// executes argument f if it's a function
// @return the return value of f
function tryFunction (f) {
    if (typeof f == 'function') {
        return f.call();
    }
    return undefined;
}
```

It will make the test a lot easier.

```
function queryJS(sql, success, error, complete) {
    tryFunction(success);
    tryFunction(error);
    tryFunction(complete);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your case

```
if(complete) complete();
```

is more than enough. Here http://jsfiddle.net/XLbVH/

Answer (score 1):

From "Maintainable JavaScript" by Nicholas C. Zakas:

> Comparing a variable against only null typically doesn't give you
>   enough information about the value to determine whether it's safe to
>   proceed. Using typeof is the best way to detect functions, because it
>   also works across frames. The only limitation is that in IE8 and earlier
>   any functions that are part of the DOM (such as document.getElementById)
>   return "object" instead of "function"

So you should use `typeof complete === "function"` parameter:

```
function queryJS(sql, success, error, complete) {
...
...
if (typeof complete === "function") complete()
...
...
```

Note: Sending SQL commans from the client side to the server side is a EXTREMELY LOW SECURITY practice. You will get SQL injections every day.

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

When you don't pass a parameter to a JS function, it doesn't get the `null` value inside. It is `undefined` instead. Also, use positive logic instead. Like this:

```
if (typeof complete == "function") complete();
```

**edit:** as jantimon put it in his answer, checking for a type is a good practice.

Comment: This is wrong: suppose that `complete` is `10`, it would result in an error.

Comment: @MatteoTassinari That kinda depends. If I inadvertently pass `10` as a parameter that's expected to be a function, I'd rather it threw an error instead of it being silently ignored.

Comment: Yeah but I think we're already going beyond the scope of the question. I do agree, though, that type checking is usually a good practice in such cases.

Answer (score 0):

When you don't pass a `complete` parameter to your function, within the function `complete` will be `undefined`.  So you can test that before running the function -

`if (typeof(complete) !== 'undefined' ) complete();`

Answer (score -1):

Change the desing of the function, is better is you work with objects. like this.

```
function jqueryJS(jsobj) {
   if (jsobj.complete) {
        jsobj.complete();

   }

}


jqueryJS({complete: function() { console.log('asfasdf');}})
```